# getMapAsync(OnMapReadyCallback) in SupportMapFragment can not be applied to ()

Tags: android

Here is the code which i wrote for Google Map project. But it is prompting error on the line no. 271 at getMapAsync().

```
 private void setUpMap(double lat,double lon) {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMapAsync();
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null) {
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(lat, lon)));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(16.0f));
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {
                    try {
                        new GetPlacesAsyncTask().execute(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude);

                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass "new OnMapReadyCallback()" to getMapAsync() method like this :-

getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback(){}):

Comment: Tried the same, but it is showing error on the point of OnMapReadyCallback(){}). Please describe in detail.

Comment: You need to write it like this :-  
mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));  

mMap.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {  
@Override  
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {  
}  
});

Comment: It's not working dear. If you have any other solution post here.